# How to use PowerShell to remove spaces after ID's listed in a .csv using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, spaces

I have a CSV that is manually updated occasionally with ID's of users here at work. I have code that does a compare on the list but some of the ID's have spaces after them so they aren't matching.

How do I do a data integrity check on this CSV to make sure only the ID names are listed? In other words remove all the spaces.

Comment: `"  string  ".trim()`. removes all leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The `.trim()` string method will remove starting or trailing spaces. There is also a `.trimend()` method for only trailing.

```
$TrimmedCSV = Import-CSV C:\example.csv | ForEach-Object {$_.ID = $_.ID.Trim(); $_} 
$TrimmedCSV | Export-CSV C:\example.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Likewise as Matt mentions, there is also `.trimstart()`. You can also trim characters besides space. For example, `.trim('a')`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. In my csv the header is $ids and I tried trim and trimend () neither works when I run and then pull up the value I still see characters after.

Comment: @socavalier Please post your code, as my code tests working: `$TrimmedCSV[1].id.length` 1 `$unTrimmedCSV[1].id.length` 2

Answer (score 0):

You can compare after stripping the spaces very easily:

```
(" SAM 500 " -replace ' ', '') -eq "SAM500"
```

Or, without seeing your code probably closer to:

```
($User -replace ' ','') -eq $oldId
```

Alternatively, (as mentioned) if you need to preserve *some* spaces, but ensure leading and trailing spaces are removed, use .Trim()

```
$NewName.Trim() -eq $prviousName
```

Or if you want to get a little creative, you could also use -Match and regex:

```
$newName -match "\s+(\b$oldName\b)+\s+"
```

Comment: _spaces after them_. Pretty sure you don't want to be messing with spaces on the inside as well.

Comment: @Matt I thought the same but being a username... I'll add trim as well though ad it would be a clearer answet

Comment: Depending on the system username can have spaces. I have an AD account that makes my OCD go crazy since it has _two_ spaces in it. Who does that.

Comment: @Matt I seem to remember an old best practices to NOT do that, specifically a MS approach.